# How do I run docker-compose using Docker.DotNet?

Tags: unit-testing, docker-compose

I would like to use [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) to run docker-compose with multiple interconnected containers. Is it possible to do this? Is there an example of how to do this?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers/tree/develop/src/DotNet.Testcontainers.Tests/Unit/Containers/Unix/MessageBroker

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?